# Why UDP checksum is optional for IPv4?

Tags: ipv4, ip-address, udp, layer4, checksum

We know that `IPv4` header has checksum for header  not for data .Therefore for checking data error we need checksum in transport layer. Suppose we're using `UDP` in `layer 4.` So if I remove the checksum option from `UDP` datagram how error will be detected? Or My question is  why `UDP` checksum is optional for `IPv4`?

Comment: "_Therefore for checking data error we need checksum in transport layer._" No, an application or application-layer protocol can implement error checking on the application data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way it is designed. You can use a checksum but you don't need to.

The application might not care so much about data corruption or your application-layer protocol might include a much better integrity check than UDP's very simple checksum. Also, there may be scenarios where it is preferrable to receive *anything* rather than *nothing at all*.

Using no checksum in the UDP header can also be a benefit - since datagrams failing checksum verification are simply dropped, the receiving application doesn't get to see them.

By explicitly *not* using the checksum option, the sender application can have damaged datagrams delivered to the receiver application just the same. Now, if the sender application also includes forward error correction (FEC) information in the UDP payload (on the application layer), that allows the receiver application to repair damaged data and receive correct data after all.

Comment: Elaborate last paragraph little bit

Comment: after receiving damaged data in receiver side, receiver repairs data in its application layer?

Comment: If the application provides forward error correction, it's got the chance to repair damaged UDP data. If the UDP checksum option is used, damaged datagrams are dropped before reaching the application and there's no chance for repair.

Comment: I want to know "Repair damaged udp data in application layer" ?

Comment: [Reed-Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) is a common FEC code, or more generally, any [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code). I'm afraid, the details are off-topic here, but could be explored on [so].

Comment: You don't understand my question... Repairing Will be happen in application layer or any other layer?

Comment: Only on the application layer - there's no function in UDP or even IP to do that.